# How to summarize matrix based on other categorical values?

Tags: r, matrix

With the three matrices:

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1));    r1=as.matrix(r1)
r2[] <-c(0,5);    r2=as.matrix(r2)
r3[] <-c(1,2,3,4,5);    r3=as.matrix(r3)
```

For each value in r3, I would like to compute the mean of all corresponding pixels in r1 but separate them if they are 0 or 5 in r2. Example take the first value in r3 =1 corresponding values in r1 are 2,1,6,8,9, which correspond in r2 as follows:

```
  2,1,9   >>> 0
  6,8    >>> 5
```

so the final result, for value 1 in r3, we have

```
 0 >>>  (2+1+9)/3= 4
 5 >>>  (6+8)/2 = 7
```

res

```
r3/r2  0   5
1    4   7
2    ?   ?
3    ?   ?
4    ?   ?
5    ?   ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example numbers you give do not match your data as the values of r1 are all between 0 and 1. Either way, with

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(1)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
r2[] <-c(0,5)
r3[] <-c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

You can do

```
r10 <- mask(r1, r2, maskvalue=5)
r15 <- mask(r1, r2, maskvalue=0)
zonal(r10, r3, mean)
zonal(r15, r3, mean)
```